# SQL server update a column group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

**TableA**

```
int  class del
null  13
null  13
null  13
12    13
null  23
null  23
null  87
null  74
null  74
null  65
32    65
```

So, I want to populate del = 'A' where for a given class, its all int is null else it should populate B.

Expected result:

**TableA**

```
int  class del
null  13    B
null  13    B
null  13    B
12    13    B
null  23    A
null  23    A
null  87    A
null  74    A
null  74    A
null  65    B
32    65    B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update
    TableA
set
    del = Case
            when mcolint is null Then 'A'
            Else 'B'
    End
from
    TableA T
inner join
    (
        select
            class,
            MAX(colint) mcolint
        from
            TableA
        group by
            class
    ) T1
on
    T.class = T1.class
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2005+ you could do something like this:

```
WITH calcDelValue AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE
      WHEN MAX(int) OVER (PARTITION BY class) IS NULL THEN 'A'
      ELSE 'B'
    END AS Value
  FROM TableA
)
UPDATE calcDelValue
SET del = Value
```

See [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to learn more about *windowing aggregate functions*, and [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for information about *CTEs (common table expressions)*.